# Change colour of linked objects in google slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a slide presentation with a number of linked objects to a google sheet, that display positive and negative figures.

Within sheets these are conditional formatted

For example
If cell value  is 1 cell is green
If cell value is  0 cell is orange
If cell value is -1 cell is red

When I link these to my slide deck it does not retain my colour formatting. Is there a way to retain conditional formatting of a range of cells through to slides?

At the moment I'm have to manually fill the linked objects background.

Can this be done through app script or any other known way?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot imagine your situation. So in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Hi I've tried to edit the post, not sure if that's helped explain?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. From `For example If cell value is 1 cell is green If cell value is 0 cell is orange If cell value is -1 cell is red`, I cannot understand about the cell range and sheet name. And I cannot understand `I link these to my slide deck`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. And, I understood that you cannot show the sample input and output you expect as the images. As an other information, can you provide your current script? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Conditional formatting is not kept while linking the cells in the Slides presentation as essentially you are only copying the cells, without the formulae.

This cannot be achieved using Apps Script as the methods specific to a `TableCell` object are presented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/table-cell) and as you can clearly see, you can only get the color of a cell but not set it.

**The only option in this case is to edit all the cells before pasting them onto the Sheet.**

You can also file a feature request for Apps Script on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script TableCell Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app)